# Cómo llamar a una función de ajax concretamente desde mi js?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tengo las siguientes funciones en un archivo ajax, donde agrego varias funciones y quisiera especificar cada función en mis js

```
class AjaxInserEval
{
    public function AgregarCapacitadorEvl()
    {
    
        $conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'desarrollo', '123456', 'tmoney');    
        $idEnt = $_POST['nidentrenados'];
        $idCap = $_POST['nidcapacitador1'];;

        $sql = "INSERT INTO evaluacion(id_entrenados,id_capacitador) values ('$idEnt','$idCap')";

        echo mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
    }

    public function AgregarComentarioFinal()
    {
        'ALGO PARECIDO'
    }
 
};

$InsertEvl = new AjaxInserEval();
$InsertEvl->AgregarCapacitadorEvl();
```

este es mi js, tengo 2 mas parecidos a este y quisiera especificar cada uno con su respectiva funcion en ajax

```
$('.btnGuardarEvFinal').click(function () {
    var datos = $('#formEvaFinal').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "view/public/ajax/AgregarCom.ajax.php",
        data: datos,
        success: function (r) {
            if (r == 1) {
                alert('exito');
      }
    });

    return false;

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Una manera rápida de hacerlo:

```
//Aquí al final pones el nombre de la función a la que quieres acceder
view/public/ajax/AgregarCom.ajax.php?f=nombre_funcion
```

Y en tu `php` dentro de la clase principal:

```
if(function_exists( $_GET['f'] )) {
  $_GET['f']();//llama la función si es que existe
}
```

Comment: Esa ruta lo pongo en el return de mi js?

Comment: Sí, en el url del ajax